# Does Java JIT compiler treat switch-over-final statements differently?

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-optimization, jit, final

Assume this demo piece of code:

```java
public List<SomeObject> filter(List<SomeObject> objects, final EnumFilterType filter) {
  ArrayList<SomeObject> output = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
  for (SomeObject subject : objects) {
    switch (filter) {
      /* whatever here */
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Here, `filter` is a final variable, which means it cannot be changed during code execution, which, in a perfect scenario, would let JIT perform more runtime optimizations, such as not generating the entire jump table and only generating the specific case matching the `filter` value. Does JIT perform such optimizations? If not, is there any reasoning behind that?

As a side note, the **bytecode** control flow isn't changed after being compiled(using JDT Core).

Comment: Declaring the variable as final won't a make difference because the compiler can clearly see for itself that it's not modified. I think what you're asking for is known as "partial evaluation". If the caller provided a filter which is a constant, then would a new version of the filter method be generated which is stripped down and inlined? I doubt it, unless the filter method itself is small enough to be inlined regardless. GraalVM has support for partial evaluation, but it might only be part of the Truffle framework.

Comment: Letting debug information aside, there is no information in bytecode, whether a local variable is final or not. As boneill correctly said, it’s the JIT compiler’s duty to find out whether a local variable is modified or not. In the end, the optimizer *can* speculatively optimize for a single branch if the code always takes this one branch, even if the variable might change.

Comment: @Holger That's the answer I was looking for, thank you.